# Adapt x-axis histogram when using dates

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a dataset of the following format "%d%m%Y" stored in variable x.
I would like to plot the frequency (per month) using a histogram.

The dates range from first of may till 31st of October.

I used the following code:

```
hist(x,"months")
```

The following graph appears

[image]

You can see that the axis is not optimal. It gives the impression that data for April is plotted while it's actually data for May.

Could somebody help me on placing the labels in the middle of the bar - Meaning that the first element would be May and it would be positioned in the middle of the bar?

---

Here is a example

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(seq(as.Date("2015-05-01"), as.Date("2015-10-31"), by="day"), 500, TRUE)
summary(x)
#         Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max. 
# "2015-05-01" "2015-06-17" "2015-07-27" "2015-07-30" "2015-09-12" "2015-10-31" 

hist(x, "months")
```

[image]

Again April appears in the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers.

This is how I worked around it in the mean time (code is not optimal (clean) as it is written to show workaround steps rather than final code):

```
#Extract month from date format
x2 <- (format(x,"%m"))

#store it as a factor
x3 <- as.factor(x2)

#Replace factor names
levels(x3) <- c("May","June","July","August","September","October")
barplot(table(x3))
```

The result would look like this.

[image]

Note that this is no density plot (histogram freq = F) but a barplot.

Condensed it could look like this I imagine (FYI - I'm a self taught "coder" so more optimal ways to create clean code are possible/welcome:

```
z <- as.factor((format(x,"%m")))

#Replacing factor names
levels(z) <- c("May","June","July","August","September","October")

#Plotting result
barplot(table(z))
```

I managed to get this working thanks to your useful tips.
However, I'm surprised that it's so difficult to create a density plot using the correct label setup. There should surely be a simpler way?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working... here is my hack job.

```
a <- hist(x, "months") # store the histogram data 
month <- strftime(x, "%m") # extract the month
dens <- (table(month)/sum(table(month)))/diff(a$breaks[-1]) # calculate the density
xax <- sort(c(as.numeric(unique(month)), max(as.numeric(unique(month))) + 1))
plot(xax, rep(max(dens), length(xax)), type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', ylim = c(0, max(dens) + .002)) # blank plot
rect(xleft = xax[-length(xax)], ybottom = 0, xright = xax[-1], ytop = dens) # draw bins
axis(1, at = xax, labels =  months(seq(as.Date("2015-05-01"), as.Date("2015-11-30"), by="month"))) # add x axis
axis(2, at = seq(0, max(dens), length = 4), labels = format(seq(0, max(dens), length = 4), digits = 2)) # add y axis
```

[image: hack hist]